# Application of sigma finiteness in a proof concerning a multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

If (X, $\Omega, \mu$) is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $\phi:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an $\Omega$-measurable function, $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, and $\phi f \in L^{p}(\mu)$ whenever $f \in L^{p}(\mu)$, then show that $\phi \in L^{\infty}(\mu)$.

I have stumbled upon the proof below and was wondering in which way sigma finiteness was used. I guess this cannot be true if one takes away sigma finiteness. Must all $\mu(B_n)$ necessarily be smaller than infinity?

[How to show following function is in $L^{\infty}(\mu)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331732/how-to-show-following-function-is-in-l-infty-mu/2331923#2331923)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in the linked answer, the measure of $B_n$ does not need to have finite measure. This can be fixed in the following way: take a non-decreasing sequence of sets $(A_\ell)$ of finite measure whose union is $X$. For a fixed $n$, since $B_n$ has a positive measure, there exists $\ell_n$ such that $B_n\cap A_{\ell_n}$ has a positive finite measure. Then continue the proof with $B_n$ replaced by $B_n\cap A_{\ell_n}$.